# Draw a square or a curb line on Google Maps using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to enhance Google Maps bit deeper. I want to draw a curb line or you can say square on GMSMapview.

How ever I have tried to draw a lines using GMSPolygon. Lines are drawn as well but also want to get touch event when anyone wants to touch curb line I should get some event.

I am not sure at this moment that Google Maps will fulfil my requirements or not.

P.S : I have used google maps already in my app and now want to draw curb line(square) and should be notified when user tap on it and I should also have facility to clear that curb line from map.

Answer (score 0):

You can user the [delegate method mapView:didTapAtCoordinate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#a9f226252840c79a996df402da9eec235) to get the coordinate and then use the method GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPath or  GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPathTolerance in the [GMSGeometryUtils module](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/group___geometry_utils)

As an alternative, as long GMSPolygon is an GMSOverlay, you can use the delegate method [mapView:didTapOverlay:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#a3a2bf2ff4481528f931183cb364c0f4b) to check if the coordinate lies on the path